# Most Efficient Way to Display Multiple SQL Rows as a Single Row with Sub-Rows in SSRS Report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

The goal is to take the data shown in the "SQL rows returned" portion of the image and display it in the "How report should look" portion of the image.  It's  currently being done using a sub-report that takes titleID, languageID, beginDate, and endDate as a parameters from the main report.  However, it's really slow to run when a significant number or records are returned.  My question is "Is there a more efficient way to accomplish the same thing in the main report w/o using a subreport?"  If more information is needed to properly assess this problem, I'll be glad to add it tomorrow.  Thank you!

[image: Data being displayed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely looking at the image.. all you need to do is put a tablix on your main report add a parent group of title_id..

Then delete the column that is created to the left (**but NOT the group**)

Right click on the detailed group -> insert row **outside** group. This will create a row inside the Title_id group but Outside the detail group.

In this line.. add the title ID, name etc.

The detail lines will show the details.. obviously.. You need to play around a bit to figure out the rest of it..

It looks to be a fairly straight forward report.. not sure why you need to use a subreport for this

Comment: Thank you!  I figured there was an easier way!